# Query camera controls in direct show

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directshow

How to query controls like brightness or contrast from camera in direct show? It seems that I just can't find anything about it. Any example or guidelines would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link describes how an application can programmatically change the image and camera settings on a video capture device: [Configure the Video Quality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd387908).
You should query the webcamera's IBaseFilter interface for interfaces like  IAMVideoProcAmp and IAMCameraControl in order to access and modify properties like: Backlight compensation, 
Brightness,
Contrast,
Gain,
Gamma,
Hue,
Saturation,
Sharpness,
White balance,
Exposure,
Focus,
Iris,
Pan,
Roll,
Tilt and 
Zoom.
You can check the amcap SDK sample for details too.